# How to sort a dictionary of nested lists by value with one key ascending and one key descending?

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I'm working on a problem that states the following:

Write a function telling apart accepted and refused students according to a threshold.
The function should be called select_student and takes as arguments:
A list where each element is a list of a student name, and his mark.
A mark. The student mark must be superior or equal to the given mark to be accepted.
Your function must return a dictionary with two entries:
Accepted which list the accepted students sorted by marks in the descending order.
Refused which list the refused students sorted by marks in ascending order.
Example

```
In [1]: from solution import select_student

In [2]: my_class = [['Kermit Wade', 27], ['Hattie Schleusner', 67], ['Ben Ball', 5], ['William Lee', 2]]

In [3]: select_student(my_class, 20)
Out[3]:
{'Accepted': [['Hattie Schleusner', 67], ['Kermit Wade', 27]],
 'Refused': [['William Lee', 2], ['Ben Ball', 5]]}

In [4]: select_student(my_class, 50)
Out[4]:
{'Accepted': [['Hattie Schleusner', 67]],
 'Refused': [['William Lee', 2], ['Ben Ball', 5], ['Kermit Wade', 27]]}
```

My code is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

students = [
            ["Kermit Wade", 27],
            ["Hattie Schleusner", 67],
            ["Ben Ball", 5],
            ["William Lee", 2],
        ]

def select_student(students, threshold):
    output = {
        'Accepted' : [],
        'Refused' : []
    }
    for i in range(len(students)):
        if students[i][1] >= threshold:
            output['Accepted'].append(students[i])
        elif students[i][1] < threshold:
            output['Refused'].append(students[i])
    return output
```

My output is:

```
{'Accepted': [['Kermit Wade', 27], ['Hattie Schleusner', 67]], 'Refused': [['Ben Ball', 5], ['William Lee', 2]]}
```

The output is for these parameters

```
print(select_student(students, 20))
```

As you can see I need to reverse the order for both accepted and refused. So Hattie comes first in accepted and then William comes first in refused.

I tried to use OrderedLists and googling but because of the nested list structure required by the problem I could not find a way to sort by the grade nor could I find a way to have it both be ascending and descending depending on the dictionary's key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dicts are ordered by default, as long as you're using python3.6+

Comment: How can I order it by ascending order for one key and descending order for a different key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your select student function to sort your accepted and refused lists as follows:

```
def select_student(students, threshold):
    output = {
        'Accepted' : [],
        'Refused' : []
    }
    for i in range(len(students)):
        if students[i][1] >= threshold:
            output['Accepted'].append(students[i])
        elif students[i][1] < threshold:
            output['Refused'].append(students[i])
    output['Accepted'] = sorted(output['Accepted'], key= lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)
    output['Refused'] = sorted(output['Refused'], key = lambda x: x[1])
    return output
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I went wrong by trying to sort output by the dict and then using subscripts so output[0][1] (which obviously didn't work) instead of sorting within the keys. I'll have to brush up on my lambda usage as well - lesson learned!

Comment: Glad I could help